# Azure Service Fabric : Support for Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I read from Microsoft documentation that it supports Linux. But seems its supporting only Java. I didn't see any information on it's support for .Net on Linux. Anyone knows more about this? I have a Web API that I could deploy successfully on Windows cluster. Trying to figure out whether it can be deployed on a Linux cluster.

Thanks You,
Jojo

Answer (score 0):

It's in limited preview now.

Check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-linux-overview/) on how to request an invite to join the program.

Comment: This answer is out of date. The Linux support is in public preview and no longer needs that somebody join any program. Use of Azure Service Fabric does not even need an Azure Subscription as it will run locally on the developer machine and on any VM offered by other Cloud providers